# Change 'points' on a line chart to donuts using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, html5-canvas, chart.js

I'm looking to customize the point on Chart.js's Line Chart a little more. What I would like is to be able to set a 'border-radius' on those points instead of a solid circle. That way, the points would show up more as donuts. (Border with a hollow/white/colored center).

Is there a way of doing this built-in? If not- is there a way to extend the LineChart function to allow this?

The easiest way I was thinking would be able to just set the PointStrokeWidth to some value greater than 1. Obviously that's not an option, but that's closer to what I'm looking for.

If possible, I would like to be able to customize 'all' of the line widths, instead of having lines all be 1px.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I seem to have overlooked the option in the documentation. For future readers:
`pointDotStrokeWidth: 1` will set the points. There is also `datasetStrokeWidth: 2`. Also, `strokeColor: '#fff'` actually uses Canvas' `strokeStyle` method, so you can use gradients and such to style those, if needed.

Comment: I don't see `pointDotStrokeWidth` in the [docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements.html?q=pointDotStrokeWidth)